# Necessary to click to show current location

Tags: ios, dictionary, click, mkmapview

I created a button to show user's current location, but it's not working correctly.
The user's location only appears if I click on it twice. The first time I click, the map shows only a blue screen.

Can anyone help?

Thanks!!

```
#import "Mapa.h"
#import "MapViewAnnotation.h"
#import "CoreLocationController.h"



@implementation Mapa

@synthesize mapView;

@synthesize stringTitle;

@synthesize minhaL;

@synthesize myAnnotation;

@synthesize stringLat;

@synthesize stringLong;

@synthesize locationManager;



- (IBAction)showCurrentLocation {
    mapView.userTrackingMode=YES;
    mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
    self.mapView.centerCoordinate = mapView.userLocation.coordinate;
    /*
     MKCoordinateRegion Region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(mapView.userLocation.coordinate, 1000,
     1000);
     MKCoordinateRegion adjustedRegion = [mapView regionThatFits:Region];
     Region.center.latitude = mapView.userLocation.coordinate.latitude;
     Region.center.longitude = mapView.userLocation.coordinate.longitude;

     Region.span.longitudeDelta = 0.01f;
     Region.span.latitudeDelta = 0.01f;

     [mapView setRegion:adjustedRegion animated:YES];
     */


}


// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    [locationManager setDelegate:self];
    [locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navBar1.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];


    CLLocationCoordinate2D location;



    NSString *latitudeA = [NSString stringWithString:stringLat];
    double valorLatitude = [latitudeA doubleValue];

    NSString *longitudeA = [NSString stringWithString:stringLong];
    double valorLongitude = [longitudeA doubleValue];


    location.latitude = valorLatitude;
    location.longitude = valorLongitude;



    // Add the annotation to our map view
    myAnnotation = [[MapViewAnnotation alloc] initWithTitle:stringTitle andCoordinate:location];
    [self.mapView addAnnotation:myAnnotation];


    MKCoordinateRegion region;
    MKCoordinateSpan span;

    span.latitudeDelta=0.02;
    span.longitudeDelta=0.02;


    region.span=span;


    [mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
    [mapView regionThatFits:region];

    [mapView setCenterCoordinate:myAnnotation.coordinate animated:YES];

}



- (void)locationManager: (CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError: (NSError *)error
{
    [manager stopUpdatingLocation];
    NSLog(@"error%@",error);
    switch([error code])
    {
        case kCLErrorNetwork: // general, network-related error
        {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"please check your network connection or that you are not in airplane mode" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [alert show];
            [alert release];
        }
            break;
        case kCLErrorDenied:{
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"user has denied to use current Location " delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [alert show];
            [alert release];
        }
            break;
        default:
        {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"unknown network error" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [alert show];
            [alert release];
        }
            break;
    }
}






// Received memory warning
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

// If the view unloads, release the map view
- (void)viewDidUnload {

}

- (void)dealloc {

    [stringLong release];

    [stringLat release];

    [myAnnotation release];

    [minhaL release];

    [stringTitle release];

    [mapView release];
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

Comment: What's your implementation of `locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:` (ios5 and less) or `locationManager:didUpdateLocations:`- you don't seem to be using the location manager updates anywhere in the code you've posted, as far as I can see

Comment: It was also missing. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to get the mapview centered on a user, you seem to be doing three of them and got all of them wrong.

1. In `showCurrentLocation` you turn on the userlocation on the map, then a micro second later you ask it for the location and try to set that as your centre, you haven't given it time.
2. In `viewDidLoad` you turn on the location manager but you haven't implemented `didUpdateToLocation` which is the method that gets called when location information is received.
3. `mapView.userTrackingMode=YES` is bad. The tracking mode is not a boolean, set it to a [valid value](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/MKUserTrackingMode) and it'll do something more useful

Here's a summary of how to use them

1. If you want to show the user's blue dot and occasionally let them center back on that location, turn on the showsUserLocation and when the button is pressed get the user's location from the map.
2. If you only want to go to the user's location when a button is pressed, and you don't need to show their location the rest of the time, start the location manager and implement the missing delegate methods. Every time *valid* location data is received, save it somewhere and when the button is pressed you can recall it and set that as center.
3. If you want the standard map button that will cycle through showing the user, tracking the user, and turning to face the way they faced then add a `MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem` and link that button to your map. It then takes care of moving the view and rotating it according to what the user presses, and it'll turn itself off if they scroll away from it.

Comment: Now i corrected the code, doing it according to the 2nd option. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Cool. Since this answer solved the problem, you need to "accept" it but clicking on the tick/check next to it so others can easily see it was the right thing to do.